# How to properly redirect an URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this url `www.site.com/page.php?sortchar=a` to `www.site.com/page/a/` with the below rule, however I cannot find the right structure. 
The `sortchar` variable can be any letter of the alphabet so I am trying to do all letters with one rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+page\.php\?sortchar=$1
RewriteRule ^ /page/([^/]*)/? [L,R]
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: @downvoter, when giving negative votes add an explanation why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$1` in `RewriteCond` without first capturing it.

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?sortchar=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: this redirects to `www.site.com/page/`. Maybe something else is also needed?

Comment: I realized it's a percentage needed. But now I face another challenge - I have a rule that redirects `www.site.com/page.php` to `www.site.com/page/` and it messes up with your code, can you help with this one as well: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/+dealer_search\.php
RewriteRule ^ /dealer-search/ [L,R]`

Comment: Just noted your comment. You should place that rule below my suggested rule.

Comment: thank you for that, I realized this is exactly what I should do later that day!